# Absolutely no way to justify text with Cufon?

Tags: cufon

Everything I've read says that you can't and furthermore, that there are no plans to make Cufon justifiable.

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Known-bugs-and-issues

A bummer, 'cause I think it's the most elegant solution solution to typeface replacement that I've seen--great text rendering regardless of the browser's rendering engine (or lack-there-of), and easy to implement. So, I'm using sIFR. I'd really love to be using Cufon, though... Before I walk away from it--I want to be sure there's no way to justify the text... Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm now using cufon for everything that doesn't need to be justified and sIFR for everything that does. Works well: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/about/ I'd still rather be all Cufon so I can fade my justified text...